# How to remove first three index of array in every loop iteration - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need to print on every loop iteration. In C# I can use Console.Write(), but in JS  - array.

So here is my code:

```
let firstNum = +gets();
let secondNum = +gets();
let thirdNum = +gets();
let line = +gets();
let array = [0, 0, 0];

print(firstNum);
print(secondNum, thirdNum);

if (line > 2) {
    for (let i = 3; i <= line; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            let tempNum = firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum;
            firstNum = secondNum;
            secondNum = thirdNum;
            thirdNum = tempNum;
            array.push(thirdNum);
            array.shift();
        }
        print(array);
    }
}
```

It's tribonacci, but my result need to be:

1

-1 1

1 1 3

5 9 17 31

But if **line** is 4 or more i get this result without shift():

1

-1 1

[ 1, 1, 3 ]

[ 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31 ]

When use shift() in my loop and put 0, 0 ,0 on start of my array i have this result:

1
-1 1
[ 1, 1, 3 ]
[ 9, 17, 31 ]

In last print I need 5, 9, 17, 31, but shift() delete 5. So it delete first 4 indexes...

How can I print in every iteration my array without first 3 indexes?

**Edit:**

The input is 1 -1 1 4

Comment: What gets() does?

Comment: It like Console.ReadLine() in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try some variants with slice() & shift() in my loop, but in every iteration it delete more or les indexes. So I change my idea & clear my array after every print iteration:

```
if (line > 2) {
    for (let i = 3; i <= line; i++) {

        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            let tempNum = bigInt(firstNum).add(secondNum).add(thirdNum);
            firstNum = secondNum;
            secondNum = thirdNum;
            thirdNum = tempNum;
            array.push(thirdNum)
        }
        print(array.toString().replace(/,/g, ' '));
        array.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping with slice().

Answer (score 1):

*How can I print in every iteration my array without first 3 indexes?*

Assuming you mean this literally, the first result here seems like it would work nicely:
[https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+print+part+of+array](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20print%20part%20of%20array)

It says:

> ***The slice() method***
>   returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object...
>
> **Syntax**
>    *array.slice(start, end)*
>
> **Parameter Values**
>   **start** Optional. An integer that specifies where to start the selection...
>   **end** Optional. An integer that specifies where to end the selection. If omitted, all elements from the start position and to the end of the array will be selected...

So this statement should  make javascript print the array without the first three indexed elements:
`console.log(array.slice(3));`

Comment: Thanks it work for case of 4 line. But when i have 5. Here is the new code: https://pastebin.com/F8Lus6WK I'll try slice in the loop...